# Concatenate only existing data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm trying to concatenate 4 columns, out of which two columns always are constant, but other two columns has to be concatenated only if thre is data inside. for EX:

**

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Result
--------------------------------------
1         2       3                123
1         2              4         124
2         3              5         235
6         7       8                678
```

i want the formula to skip the column in which there is not data and select the column which consists of only data dont want any blank spaces or any character in-between the formula.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  If there's no data, there'll be nothing to concatenate.  So what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

So, how about this:

After the edit of the question, this will work:

```
=A1&B1&C1&D1
```

But if you want it as a numerical value then do *1

```
=(A1&B1&C1&D1)*1
```

[image]

The & does the concatenation including spaces, the trim removes double or more spaces down to only one...